# move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpVZ330Q' to 'uploads/dining.jpg' in /website/nomination-form.php on line 33

Tags: php

Full error message:

```
 PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpVZ330Q' to 'uploads/dining.jpg' in /var/www/website.mediaclash.co.uk/siteroot/nomination-form.php on line 33, referer: http://website.co.uk/nominations.php
```

Hi all,

I'm trying to send a form to server which sends the data to an email address. However i'm having problems with the file uploading. I'm getting the error above when i try and upload the file. I've changed all permissions on the site directory to 775 but it's made no change. It seems like it's getting the correct target path and posting the file name.

This is new to me so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is my PHP:

//Where the file is going to be uploaded
$target_path = "uploads/";

```
//Add the original file name to our target path
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
    echo "The file" . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    "has been uploaded";
}else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try agaian.";
    }



<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="5120000" />
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
```

I hope this is enough info. let me know if you need me to provide any more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've changed all permissions on the site directory to 775 but it's
>   made no change.

Change that to **`777`**

Answer (score 0):

use 
    getcwd()
in order to display the current location (working directory) before calling 
    move_uploaded_file
and make sure directory 
    'uploads' 
is there

otherwise modify 
    $target_path
to an absolute path